# Displaying items in Array Controller ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following the official TodoMVC tutorial from Ember.js website. Everything works until the step to display model data: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/

The error I'm getting is 
`Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <(generated application controller):ember280>` when trying to access each element in the controller with `{{#each controller}}` as instructed.

The error disappeared when I changed it into `{{#each controller.content}}`. However, nothing was displayed. The documentation said that

> This controller is an instance of ArrayController that Ember.js has provided for us as the container for our models

and the [API](http://emberjs.com/api) listed `length` as a property of the `ArrayController` class. But when I tried to `{{log controller.length}}` and `{{log controller.content.length}}`, I got `undefined` as the result.

All this suggested that `controller` is not an instance of the `Array Controller` class, at least not anymore. So how can I display my model data now?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are right, the ArrayController has a length property which returns the length of its content....The content property of an ArrayController should be an array...

sample working fiddle

http://jsbin.com/ikijoq/1/edit